# When turning Alucard, from Hellsing Ultimate, into a Vampire what is the best build?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

In this case I'm wanting to turn Alucard, from Hellsing Ultimate, into a Vampire in Vampire the Masquerade and/or Vampire: The Dark Ages using the V20 rules. Or 20th Annivesary rules. No fifth edition rules.

Here are a (brief) list of powers at the [Disposal of Alucard from Hellsing Ultimate](https://hellsing.fandom.com/wiki/Alucard#Powers_and_Abilities):

1. Superhuman Strength: As a true vampire, Alucard is inherently strong. To start, his guns Jackal and Casull are far too unwieldy for a human to hold, let alone use, but he does both with ease. He has been seen going up barehanded against even some supernatural weapons and destroying them, such as Tubalcain's magic cards. Despite their armor, Alucard was able to disembowel and tear apart several police officers with one hand. The extent of his strength is unknown, though it appears to vary with the release state that he is in, as his black, jumpsuit clad form has significantly greater feats of strength and durability than his other forms.
2. Superhuman Speed and Reflexes: Alucard is too fast for the human eye to follow, but other vampires such as Walter[1](https://hellsing.fandom.com/wiki/Alucard#Powers_and_Abilities) and Tubalcain Alhambra[2] can keep pace with him just fine. Alexander Anderson, a regenerator, can also do this, near-matching him step for step and blow for blow in a fight. Alucard's reaction times are top-notch, letting him catch Rip Van WIinkle's bullets with his teeth, despite a single one of these bullets penetrating an SR-71 blackbird multiple times while the plane was moving as fast as possible. It also safe to assume that same as strength his reflexes and speed becomes more potent in other forms.
3. Enhanced Endurance: Alucard takes most damage without flinching or making a sound, quietly allowing the enemy to attack before retaliating tenfold. He can even attack after being torn asunder by bullets. After Rip Van Winkle crashes his Blackbird, he exits the craft without a scratch and easily destroys everyone aboard, even as they use high caliber weaponry on him. He's been thrown through skyscrapers, bled excessively, and even Walter knows of no certain way to defeat him other than killing him again and again until he stays down.
4. Enhanced Durability: Alucard appears to have the ability to harden the surface of his body to the point where, in a direct clash with one of Tubalcain Alhambra's playing cards, he was able to shred it apart without any difficulty despite the cards having been demonstrated to be able to cut a depleted uranium cannon shell in half.
5. Combat Experience: In addition to his superhuman abilities, Alucard also possesses centuries of combat experience. While he usually relies on crushing his opponents with sheer power, he does at times use strategy. When he fought Alhambra, Alucard used shadow duplicates to distract him, allowing Alucard to close the distance between them and deliver the death blow.
6. Regeneration: Alucard has the ability to perfectly and quickly recover from any physical injury. He has been torn to shreds by conventional weaponry and holy weaponry designed to kill his kind and has survived all of it. Holy weapons, while they do affect him more, are regenerated all the same if not as quickly.[3]
7. Extrasensory Perception: Alucard has senses that are not only sharper than a mortal's, affording him abilities such as perfect accuracy, but he has abilities that they completely lack. In particular he possesses a 'third-eye' which allows him to see things from far, far distances.[4] Though he never uses it to do so, he can likely see through things that fool human eyes, as Seras does when facing Zorin Blitz.[5] This is not an inherent ability and must be used consciously, as Alucard was unable to see through Tubalcain's illusionary clones. Similarly, Seras was unable to see through Zorin's illusions until told outright that's what they were.
8. Dark Composition: Though he generally dons a corporeal, humanoid form, Alucard is made up of a highly variable otherworldly substance that is black in core and reddish on its edges.[6] This can be especially seen whenever he takes heavy damage, the darkness being immune to conventional weaponry. Along with composing his being, it can serve as a weapon. Alucard is able to transform this material into virtually anything he chooses, like a puddle of goo.
9. Intangibility: Alucard has the ability to walk through solid objects, such as walls.
10. Immortality: It is unclear if Alucard is a true immortal, but he is at least biologically immortal, immune to disease and aging. Alucard has suffered all manner of injury to the most extreme degrees, only to reform himself. This seems to indicate structural immortality as well, but the vampire himself asserts that there is no such thing as a true immortal.[8] This means his immortality is only biological, and there is a way to kill him. Anderson's talk of him being "alone"[9] and his duel with Walter implies that after his seals are removed, his heart is vulnerable to being impaled if not other forms of destruction, which would in turn destroy him for good. After absorbing Schrödinger, his immortality may have been augmented, but if so, it is not known how.
11. Hematophagy: As a vampire, Alucard has the ability to consume blood raw. He has long, conical fangs to assist in this job as well as serpentine-like tongue. His feeding habits have been seen to vary: from the traditional neck-biting[10] to simply ripping people to pieces and outright devouring them. Alucard doesn't seem to need blood to survive, however if starved of of it, he will enter an inactive death-like state.

And that's not getting into his various other forms. With this in mind how would you create a Vampire like Alucard using V20 Vampire rules?

Comment: If I could, I would vote to close this question. RPG:SE is not the place for "How would you build X?" questions

Comment: @wheatleycrab We do accept questions on how to create a build with certain requirements.

Comment: @NautArch Where can I find those requirements? I'd rather avoid this awkward scenario again.

Comment: @wheatleycrab See this meta post for some guidance (based on D&D 5e, though general principles may still apply): [How do I ask a good character build/optimization question for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8123). Here is our more general FAQ question: [Are character build or optimization questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1639)

Answer (score 5):

### Frame challenge

Alucard in Hellsing is [supposed to be Dracula](https://hellsing.fandom.com/wiki/Alucard#Identity), who [is an actual character](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Dracula_(VTM)) in the Old World of Darkness Transylvanian Chronicles.

In those books, Vlad Tepes/Dracula is a 5th generation Tzimisce, after diablerizing his way up his own genealogy.

As a 5th generation Tzimisce, he could have access to some rather fitting uses of **Vicissitude** and **Animalism** (turning into living pools of blood, summoning animals/wolves, basically ignoring stakes, et cetera).

Comment: I think that this answer could be improved if you addressed how Dracula's Disciplines applied to grant him the listed powers.